# Active MQ QueueBrowser returning very high number of messages than actual

Tags: activemq-classic

Hi i am new to ActiveMQ,

We are using Active MQ-5.8.0 as  message broker for our system.My requirement is to get a alert mail if the number of messages in a particular Queue exceeds some specified number(configurable) . So i found that that we can use QueueBrowser to get the list of messages.

Below is the code snippet:

```
    enum1 = TestQBrowser.getEnumeration();
        int count = 0;
        while(enum1.hasMoreElements()){
            count++;
            enum1.nextElement();
        }

                    if(count>5)
                 sendMail("Queue has more pending message than threashold 5");//logic to send alert mail.
```

This was working as expected previously but i found a strange number (1113762 messages) in queue however when i checked the same with ActiveMQ admin console there are only 100 message.
Can you please help me why i am getting this high count of messages. Is there any problem with the way i did or some problem with QueueBrowser??

P.S : This is my first question in StackOverflow , this question might be basic one but i have been spending a lot of time on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in ActiveMQ 5.8 that causes this.  You need to move to version 5.9.0 if you want to reliably use the QueueBrowser to try and do this.  However you will still probably run into issues if the Queue is to deep as there is no guarantee that the browser will return all the messages since it must work within the configured memory limits which can cause it to stop paging in messages from the store.

Comment: :If it was memory limit issue ,it should return less number of messages than actual right??. I believe that , problem could be in getEnumeration() method which is returning current queue messages rather than  messages at the time TestQBrowser.getEnumeration() is called.For example, say there are 5 messages in queue when getEnumeration() is called by the time we count++ ,say some other 10 messages are added , now enum1.nextElement() is looping up to 15(5+10)  instead of 5??

Comment: As I said, there's a bug in v5.8.0 related to QueueBrowsers.   Upgrade to 5.9.0 and try again.   Reading, it's fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How can I monitor ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html), there are many possibilities.

Probably the [Advisory Messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) are the best for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for this.But need very basic monitoring like above, Did you get any chance to look at the QueueBrowser count issue mentioned above?